# Make javascript only apply to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, html

Any know of a way to make javascript/jquery only apply to everything inside a div or iframe?

As an example:
I have a cool javascript function that makes my text change colours, but it changes the colours of the entire page of text when I only want it to change the text inside a div or iframe.

Any ideas?

Here is some code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { //  When the document is ready
    $.foo({
            fontchange: true,             //  Make the text pretty
        });
    });
</script>
```

EDIT: This seems to be more trouble than it is worth, thanks for the help.

Comment: Code is worth a thousand words.

Comment: When writing your javascript/jQuery code, you instruct it on how to act, and what parts of the page to affect. We'd need to see the code to be able to comment on what specific parts to change. A lot of jQuery snippets are as simple as `$('everything').myPlugin();` which you'd only have to change to `$('subset-of-everything').myPlugin();`.

Comment: @McDan Garrett: Thanks for the code.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Updated answer** after code was posted:

Your posted code `$.foo({fontchange: true})` suggests you're using a jQuery plug-in which is somewhat unusual, in that it doesn't work on a set of selected elements. That's not how plug-ins usually work, so we can't help without knowing what plug-in you're dealing with (presumably its documentation talks about how to make it more targeted).

The **usual** use of a jQuery plug-in is that first you get a set of elements to act on, usual selectors (see below), and then you call the plug-in function on them. E.g., `$("some selector here").foo({fontchange: true});`. But that's not how this particular, unusual plug-in seems to work.

---

**Original answer**:

You've tagged your question `jquery`, so: You can get a jQuery wrapper around any element or set of elements on your page for which you can write a [CSS3 selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) (and a [few more](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)) and the [`jQuery`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) function, which is usually also available via its alias `$`.

So for instance, if you have a `div` with an `id` of `"foo"`, this will get a jQuery instance for that `div` using the CSS selector `#foo`:

```
var foo = $("#foo");
```

If you have a bunch of `span`s inside a `div`, you can get them using the usual descendant selector syntax:

```
var spans = $("div span");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function probably references `document.body` at some point to get the nodes to change. Instead of `document.body`, give it something else. In the case of most elements, just passing the element is fine. In the case of an `iframe`, however, the page inside MUST be from the same origin (scheme, host, port) and you need to pass the frame's `contentDocument` (and optionally a specific element from there).

Comment: Sorry I am not at all good with javascript, How could I turn `document.body` into what it needs to be to apply to a div with the id "Foo"?

Comment: I mean, what does `document.body` need to be replaced with?

Answer (score 1):

Most jQuery calls use what's called a "selector" to select the elements to work on.  Your code probably looks something like:

```
$('body').do_cool_stuff();
```

to select the whole body.  `'body'` is the selector there, and you can change it to:

```
$('#somediv').do_cool_stuff();
```

to select only a single div:

```
<div id='somediv'>...</div>
```

The `#` in the selector corresponds with the `id` attribute of the `div`.

**Edit,** now that we have some code: try changing `$.foo(...)` into `$('#somediv').foo(...)`.

Comment: @McDanGarrett: Then you'll need to give us a lot more information, eg. what the `foo()` function actually looks like.  (Is it really called `foo()` or is a jQuery plugin that we can go and look at?)  The ideal thing to do would be to post a failing example on jsfiddle.

Comment: The function (found in foo.js) is just something I downloaded and added that code to my site, seems more trouble than it's worth, thanks for the help.